# Client Side Java Web technologies

Tags: java, web, webclient

I have a bunch of shell scripts on every client machine. I need a web interface to provide settings for these scripts and it should invoke these scripts.

If i run a web application from a server to run scripts, it will overload the server due to multiple client requests, so client side web app is preferred.

Applets can solve this. But, it is outdated and I dont like it.

Is there any other new/good technologies to do such client side computing ?

Comment: clientside means desktop applications?

Comment: What do you mean with "I need to run unix shell scripts using web interface on client side"? Do you want to run the scripts on a unix server but initiate them from a desktop client (any platform)?

Comment: This question is not making sense to me. Please add some description as what you wanted to achieve and what are you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about web application or desktop application? 
If this is a web application, so as far as I know - no. You must use applet embedded at your web page to run the script. 
If desktop application - it can use the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for execution processes at Java. 
Another option is maybe to download some small server code that will be used to invoke scripts, and have you web application communicate with it, in order to invoke a process. 
The downside of this is that this is not a "straightforward" usage of your web application.